# “Sir,' I said to the universe, 'I exist.' 'That,' said the universe, 'creates no sense of obligation in me whatsoever.”

Tags: phrases, expressions

> *'Sir,'* I said to the universe, *'I exist.'*
>
> *'That,'* said the universe, *'creates no sense of obligation in me whatsoever.'*

Does the statement mean the universe does not care about you existing or not? Is there deeper meaning to that quote?

Comment: What's the context of this quote?

Comment: I am delighted that you asked that question. And I hope that you get some excellent answers.  But I do not feel obliged to remember your birthday or pay your school fees. The universe probably feels even more delight when someone says, "I exist," but it is not obliged to intervene.

Comment: Stephen Crane, too.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro I can't find the quote in _The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy_ (and I don't see in what context it would appear in that book). Are you sure that's the book it's from? Was it perhaps one of the sequels?

Comment: @IQAndreas It is all over the internet attributed to Douglas Adams in *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* but like you I find that doubtful.  A quick search at a page with the text of the five books could not find a single example of the word "obligation" (there are three examples of "obliged" in *The Restaurant at the End of the Universe*).

Comment: @IQAndreas: And medica has pointed out it was written by [Stephen Crane](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Stephen_Crane) (died 1900)

Comment: This does sound very Douglas Adamsish (it's written in his style), but I don't recall reading anything like it in the (increasingly inaccurately named) Hitchhiker's Guide trilogy. Perhaps a different book?

Comment: A single skin cell on my elbow is a far greater part of me than I am a part of the Universe. I can't recall any conscious concern over any given skin cell even after bumping my elbow on some hard object. We apparently often think of ourselves as being somehow _separate_ from the Universe, but...

Comment: @Doorknob The title gave me a good laugh when I read it but beyond that I see no similarity to Douglas Adams' work.

Comment: It's offtopic as literary interpretation.

Comment: This has utterly nothing to do with Douglas Adams.  It's a great pity that, people who mentioned this, do not delete it.  Crap builds up on the internet due to google's algorithms; it propagates nonsense.

Comment: Not only is this off-topic as literary interpretation, it is doubly off-topic as having nothing to do with English. If you read the quote in French or Russian, you'd still have the exact same question. You are asking for an interpretation of an abstract idea, a train of thought, that is in no way tied to or relies on the particular language it happens to be expressed in. As far as the particular language is concerned, "creates no sense of obligation in me whatsoever" means just that: "creates no sense of obligation in me whatsoever". No idioms or puns, nothing. Just plain words.

Comment: Why are we discussing this here, rather than on [philosophy.se] ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> A Man Said to the Universe By Stephen Crane
>   A man said to the universe:
>   “Sir, I exist!”
>   “However,” replied the universe,
>   “The fact has not created in me
>   A sense of obligation.”

In another Crane poem ("War is Kind"):

> Hoarse, booming drums of the regiment,
>   Little souls who thirst for fight,
>   These men were born to drill and die.
>   The unexplained glory flies above them,
>   Great is the Battle-God, great, and his Kingdom -
>   A field where a thousand corpses lie.

The comparison should be ample to explain Crane's view of the universe or the almighty.

These men (dying in horribly in the trenches) were "born to drill and die"... fairly cold and detached, isn't it?

An editor [(Christopher Benfey)](http://americanpoetsproject.loa.org/volume/1598530933) of Crane's poetry describes his aim:

> ...to identify the truth about human existence as he conceives it, *a truth that is difficult and austere*, and rescue it from what he perceives to be competing and overly facile versions of it.

That is the universe. Cold, detached, feeling no obligation to us for the quality of our existence.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it does not necessarily mean that the universe not 'caring' about your existence. Take parents for example. Regardless of you stating the nature of your existence or not, they have an obligation to you. They feed, clothe, and teach you. The universe implies that it won't help you in your endeavors by just handing things to you.

If you're looking for greater meaning, the universe could represent God, or a deity, implying that they created you and don't necessarily have to take care of you, rather let you discover things for your own and learn.

Answer (score 6):

I think it means that we shouldn't expect the universe (or the world, or other people, or the government) to provide us with what we need just because we *exist*. Our existence doesn't magically create some sort of *obligation* in others to care for us, or support us.

I understand this as meaning that you should work for (i.e. earn) things you want, rather than trying to convince other people that they owe you something just because you exist.

Think of it it as *"the world doesn't owe you anything"*. It is quite liberating actually. It makes you take responsibility for your life and not blame others for things you might see as unfair or unjust.

Answer (score 3):

It's the universe personified, talking. In the world of humans, narrowed down to relationships, the statement, "I exist" may mean a few things in different scenarios.

For the universe, of which I am an insignificant part, my existence means nothing. Why? The universe is unimaginably immense. The statement, "I exist" demands attention in human relationships, but that's of no consequence to the universe. It's like the tiny ant talking to an elephant. The elephant might say, "Oh, okay" and go about its business. Or, he might respond with a question: "So what?"

The message here may be an attack on the insignificant human ego, which at times feels great or invincible.

Comment: I agree with the reading that the message is an attack on the human ego.  The point is not so much that the universe doesn't care, it's that man addresses the universe as though it *should*.

Comment: Yes, that attitude comes from the self-assertive importance one gives to oneself by saying: "I am important. I exist. Don't forget me!", etc.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the Disney classic short of the grasshopper and the ants jumped right to my mind with that quote: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3V9uL_ruafU

I exist. I shout out to the universe announcing my existence. the universe acknowledges this as fact, but expresses the opinion that this is entirely incidental to its own existence. My existence, and the quality of my existence are of no concern to it. It just happens to be the environment in which my existence occurs - nothing more and nothing less, and to presume that it will alter its own existence or actions in order to aid in my own life is presumptuous on my part.

Maybe it will. Or maybe its actions for other reasons will wind up being beneficial to me. But I can't assume that it feels obliged to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think it denies other quotes such as the following from The Alchemist by Paulo Coelho:

“And, when you want something, all the universe conspires in helping you to achieve it.”

Humans tend to think they are the most important thing that ever happened to the universe. The thing is, it existed long before we did, and it will live long after we perish.

Comment: I like this observation, and agree with it, but as a nitpick: just because the universe helps you when you want something, doesn't mean it is _obliged_ to do so.   So technically the two statements are not at odds with each other.

Answer (score 1):

The universe has no obligation to any existence. In this context, the meaning of obligation if taken as "a grateful feeling that you have toward someone who has done something for you"([Ref](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/obligation)), then it implies that this person's existence doesn't make the Universe feel any gratitude.

If we take the other definition as "something that you must do for legal or moral reasons"([Ref](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/obligation)), even then the Universe has no moral obligation towards the existence of this person or anyone or anything. If the Universe is made up of matter and we are a consequence of it, then the Universe need not feel obligated towards it.

Here's an interesting quote:[citation](http://www.theguardian.com/science/2010/sep/02/stephen-hawking-big-bang-creator)

> "The fact that we human beings – who are ourselves mere collections of fundamental particles of nature – have been able to come this close to an understanding of the laws governing us and our universe is a great triumph."
>
> Hawking says the first blow to Newton's belief that the universe could not have arisen from chaos was the observation in 1992 of a planet orbiting a star other than our Sun. "That makes the coincidences of our planetary conditions – the single sun, the lucky combination of Earth-sun distance and solar mass – far less remarkable, and far less compelling as evidence that the Earth was carefully designed just to please us human beings," he writes.

Adding Carl Sagan's [quote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/c/carlsagan137410.html) -->

> The universe seems neither benign nor hostile, merely indifferent.

Comment: I have added a citation. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For fuller context, here is Stephen Crane, "[A Man Said to the Universe](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/173305)" published in 1899 as part of Crane's [*War Is Kind and Other Lines*](https://public.wsu.edu/%7Ecampbelld/crane/warkind.htm):

> A man said to the universe:
>
> “Sir, I exist!”
>
> “However,” replied the universe,
>
> “The fact has not created in me
>
> A sense of obligation."

I have always imagined this poem to be a response to the opening lines in Alfred Tennyson's "[By an Evolutionist](https://books.google.com/books?id=jn5RAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA370&lpg=PA370&dq=Tennyson+%22By+an+Evolutionist%22&source=bl&ots=GYmjz6hbWe&sig=5oXet7J9_q0APiLIiMGLrUhP-C4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6KOEVdC0BNLGogSs3oKAAw&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Tennyson%20%22By%20an%20Evolutionist%22&f=false)," from [*Demeter, and Other Poems*](https://archive.org/details/demeterotherpoem00tennuoft) (1889):

> The Lord let the house of a brute to the soul of a man,
>
> And the man said, 'Am I your debtor?'
>
> And the Lord—'Not yet : but make it as clean as you can,
>
> And then I will let you a better.'

In each case, "a man" is unaccountably able to converse with "the universe" or "the Lord" about their relationship. Tennyson's poem suggests that life is sort of like a starter pet—a pet goldfish, say: Take care of it and maybe you can have a pet dog—or as Tennyson implies, a resplendent home in heaven—someday. Crane's view, to the contrary, seems to be that this is all there is, the universe is uninterested in a man's (or for that matter, any human being's) existence, so get used to it.

I still can't figure out how "a man" manages to draw such an articulate response from either entity.

Answer (score 0):

This answer focuses exclusively on the widespread attribution of the "'Sir,' I said to the universe, 'I exist'" quotation to Douglas Adams. I recognize that this issue is tangential to the OP's question, but if it is indeed a false attribution, I think, it ought to be exploded if possible.

As IQAndreas and Henry note in comments beneath the poster's question, the quotation is not easy to find among the various hydra heads of *The Hitchhiker's Guide*. That is because Douglas Adams probably never wrote it. What he did write is interesting in its own right, and similar enough to be confused or merged with Stephen Crane's much earlier statement in "A Man Said to the Universe"—especially if the person doing the confusing and merging is operating from memory rather than from either original text. From Douglas Adams, [*The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy: Original Radio Scripts*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6LgGIvmSce0C&pg=PT37&dq=%22such+a+bizarrely+improbable+coincidence+that+anything%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=traFVb6DLo2sogSx_JaoDg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22such%20a%20bizarrely%20improbable%20coincidence%20that%20anything%22&f=false), Fit the First (as originally broadcast in 1978):

> **NARRATOR:** The Babel Fish is small, yellow, leechlike, and probably the oddest thing in the Universe. It feeds on brainwave energy, absorbing all unconscious frequencies and then excreting telepathically a matrix formed from the conscious frequencies and nerve signals picked up from the speech centres of the brain; the practical upshot of which is that if you stick one in your ear you can instantly understand anything said to you in any form of language—the speech you hear decodes the brainwave matrix. Now it is such a bizarrely improbable coincidence that anything so mindbogglingly useful could evolve purely by chance that some thinkers have chosen to see it as a final clinching proof of the non-existence of God.
>
> The argument goes something like this:
>
> 'I refuse to prove that I exist' says God, 'for proof denies faith, and without faith I am nothing'. 'But', says Man, 'the Babel Fish is a dead giveaway, isn't it? It proves you exist, and so therefore you don't. QED'. 'Oh dear,' says God, 'I hadn't thought of that' and promptly vanishes in a puff of logic. 'Oh, that was easy' says Man, and for an encore he proves that black is white and gets killed on the next zebra crossing.

The odd thing here is that, rather than having a man tell the universe that he exists, Adams's quote has God telling Man that He refuses to prove His existence. Nevertheless, I suspect that the innocently fallible gods of the Internet managed to mash up a seriously flawed memory of Adams's quote with a slightly flawed memory of Crane's quote—and then attributed the result to Adams.

The tell-tale sign of false attribution of a quotation, obviously, is that no one can find the quoted wording *in situ* in the supposed author's work. A Google Books search has this problem with "'Sir,' I said to the universe, 'I exist.'" The only two books that find the phrase at all—Richard Rapson, [*Amazed by Life: Confessions of a Non-religious Believer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=so4xeCidLxEC&pg=PA14&dq=%22I+said+to+the+universe,+I+exist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O8SFVd28K9HFogThtIBo&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22I%20said%20to%20the%20universe%2C%20I%20exist%22&f=false) (2003) and James Houston, [*The Fulfillment: Pursuing True Happiness*](https://books.google.com/books?id=W2SM6V7rzx0C&pg=PA122&dq=%22I+said+to+the+universe,+I+exist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F8eFVYWnF9jaoASut6ToDw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20said%20to%20the%20universe%2C%20I%20exist%22&f=false) (2007)—attribute it to Crane, evidently without looking up Crane's poem to get the correct wording. Rapson is quite free (and flat) with his quotation:

> This, despite Stephen Cranes dismaying ditty: “'Sir, I said to the Universe/ I exist.'/ Said the Universe to me/ 'That is of no interest to me.'"

And Houston's epigraph from Crane omits the crucial word *not* from the already-unfaithful-to-the-original wording:

> *“Sir,” I said to the universe, “I exist.” “However,” replied the universe, “that fact has created in me a sense of obligation."* —Stephen Crane

None of the books in the Google Books database (which includes a number of editions of *The Hitchhiker's Guide*) claim the phrase as Adams's.